# How to filter data with help of engine without using query?

Tags: jasper-reports

We a have a report that execute by a Stored Procedure.

We need custom filters in report that filters out data after filling the report with *JasperReports*. We cannot use input control for this as it calls the Stored Procedure every time.

Is there any mechanism like: take the data set into heap once the whole report executed and filter the data from the heap and execute the report based on filters.

Answer (score 2):

Filtering can be implemented is several ways.

#### 1. Using custom datasource

You can fetch data and add it to the custom datasource. For example the *[JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html)* can be used.

The data can filtered during constructing the datasource. 
For getting new data we need to generate new report with new datasource.

#### 2. Using filterExpression

The ***filterExpression*** property can be added to the main datasource or *subDataset*. This expression can help to filter data in way you want.

The list of six values (names of cities) is filtering by containing some character in this sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Filtering data" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <subDataset name="ds">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="value" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <filterExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}.contains("o")]]></filterExpression>
    </subDataset>
    <summary>
        <band height="15">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="311" height="15"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="ds">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(Arrays.asList("Moscow", "London", "Paris", "New York", "Delhi", "Berlin"))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="15" width="311">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="311" height="15"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The output result in *Jaspersoft Studio*:

[image: Filtered data]

Only three values remain after applying the filter.

The parameters can be used in the ***filterExpression***.

For example using this *subDataset* (from the example above):

```
<subDataset name="ds">
    <parameter name="filter">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["e"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <field name="value" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <filterExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}.contains($P{filter})]]></filterExpression>
</subDataset>
```

we are getting this result:

[image: Filtering with parameters]

This method of filtering can be applied for any datasource.